# Writing a method ByteSwap but not working as planned

Tags: c#, c++, c

so we need to write a method

byteSwap - swaps the nth byte and the mth byte

- Examples: byteSwap(0x12345678, 1, 3) = 0x56341278
- byteSwap(0xDEADBEEF, 0, 2) = 0xDEEFBEAD
- You may assume that 0 <= n <= 3, 0 <= m <= 3
- Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

also we cannot use loops/recursion

but my following code fails with this test case :

Test byteSwap(-2147483648[0x80000000],0[0x0],3[0x3]) failed...
...Gives -128[0xffffff80]. Should be 128[0x80]

not sure why though this is my code so far

```
int byteSwap(int x, int n, int m) { 
int nBitShift = n << 3;  
int mBitShift = m << 3;
int nByte = x & (0xFF << nBitShift);  //gets the byte at position n
int mByte = x & (0XFF << mBitShift);  //gets the byte at position m 
int newX = x + ~(nByte + mByte) + 1; //make 0's in the nth and mth byte
nByte = nByte >> nBitShift; //shift back    
nByte = nByte << mBitShift; //shift to the mth spot
mByte = mByte >> mBitShift;  //shift back   
mByte = mByte << nBitShift; //shift to the nth spot

return nByte + mByte + newX;
```

}

edit:yes this is hw, but i need help

Comment: "we", so this is surely a homework. :D

Comment: Which language are you writing for?  Is this homework?  Why do you add 1 to "newX"?

Comment: Also: bitwise shifts on negatives is implemenatation-defined behavior.  I don't specifically see a shift on a negative value, but just to be aware.

Comment: language is c. im adding 1 because when you ~(value) like ~5 will give -6 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arithmetic shift of a signed value sign-extends the operand. If you switch the type of your temporary variables to `unsigned`, your solution would avoid this problem.

Comment: This worked thank you so much. but i dont fully understand what you mean by "extends" the operand

Comment: @user1186549 [This atricle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) explains sign extension. [This other article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) has a nice picture showing what happens to MSB when the number is shifted right.

Comment: is there a way to do it with using unsigned? the assignment does not give me points if i use unsigned.... i am always off by 1 when there are negative numbers

Comment: @user1186549 You could add code to zero out the most significant bit after shifting back. Start with only the MSB set, shift it to the right nBitShift/mBitShift, invert with `~`, and use `&` to clear out the ones that got shifted in. Alternatively you can shift by one, clear out the MSB, and then shift by (mBitShift-1).

Answer (score 1):

How would this work?

```
int byteswap(int x,int n,int m)
{
    unsigned char *x_bytes = (unsigned char*)&x, tmp = x_bytes[n];
    x_bytes[n] = x_bytes[m];
    x_bytes[m] = tmp;
    return x;
}
```

I know it's probably not what your lecturer/somebody had in mind, but it was just to show an idea. If anything, it doesn't use loops nor recursion. ;)

Comment: Isn't the method dependent on endian-ness of the CPU.  By the above definition byte 0 is least-significant byte and this method would not work on CPUs where the MSB is stored first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "fancier" solution.

```
unsigned int byteswap(const unsigned int x, unsigned int n, unsigned int m) {
    unsigned int mask;
    m <<= 3;
    n <<= 3;
    mask = ((x >> m) ^ (x >> n)) & 0xFFU;
    mask = (mask << m) | (mask << n);
    return (x ^ mask);
}
```